# Text to a list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of text that I'd like to read in python and convert into a `,` separated list.

```
1800000000001
1000000000001
4200000000001
4000000000011
....
....
....
0400000000011
6420000000000
8660000000000
```

1. Read text data
2. Format text as strings and convert to a `,` separated

Final output

```
l = ['1800000000001', '1000000000001', '4200000000001', '4000000000011'.....]
```

Is there a way to do this without read the text data as `csv`?

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file

```py
_file = open("file.txt","r")
out = _file.readlines()
print(out) #your data in a list
```

Maybe, you need to replace the char `\n` in the final strings.

```
out = [item.replace("\n","") for item in out]
```

Answer (score 2):

This method only needs to pass through your text once~

```
data = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip())
```